# How can i request api more faster in for loop?

Tags: reactjs, api, for-loop, request, axios

I developing my toy project with riot api.(league of legends game) 
And I have a question. as you can see I request to riot api in for loop.
It take 20 seconds... this is the problem. I think riot api is not a problem.
I think just request in for loop is the problem. 
How can I make it faster than now? help me please ㅠ.ㅠ

```
  for (let cnt = 0; cnt < 20; cnt++) {
    let temp = await api.getMatchInfo(res.matches[cnt].gameId);
    if (temp.gameMode === "CLASSIC" && temp.gameDuration >= 800) {
      console.log("gameList:", temp);
      temp["cnt"] = cnt;
      gameList.push(temp);
      rankCnt++;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sequence request each for loop, you can make it parallel by `Promise.all`. You can see more here https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const promises = []
for (let cnt = 0; cnt < 20; cnt++) {
  promises.push(api.getMatchInfo(res.matches[cnt].gameId)  
}
Promise.all(promises).then(games => {
  console.log(games)
})
//or
const games = await Promise.all(promises)
console.log(games)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will try it!! :)